# Dynamic endpoint with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I'm trying to generate a dynamic URL that will change everytime an endpoint is called
So I have this simple function in Node.js to create a dynamic url:

```
var path = crypto.createHash('md5').update(`${Date.now()}`).digest("hex");

function createNewPath(){
  path = crypto.createHash('md5').update(`${Date.now()}`).digest("hex");
}
```

and this simple code to receive the request:

```
app.use('/'+path, function(req,res){
  createNewPath();
  res.send("<h1>Welcome!<h1>");
});
```

The problem is that app.use does not reload the value in "path" so the initial url asigned stays the same, any ideas?

Been breaking my head and got nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create the route dynamically. Set it up in advance. Check the hash inside it.

Create a route which takes the hash as a param.

Return an error if it doesn't match.

```
app.get("/:hash", (req, res) => {

    if (req.params.hash === path) {
        return res.send("<h1>Welcome!<h1>");
    }
    return res.sendStatus(404);
});
```